# Convert d3.js graph to pdf in reactjs using jsPDF

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, canvas, jspdf

I have been trying to create the pdf file of d3.js sunburst diagrams. And, I am using reactjs for frontend. I have tried few reactjs packages for that for example, react-pdf, d3-save-pdf. But, they are not giving me desired results. So, I am working with jsPDF.

According to the articles available online, the process for this is to get the svg element, put that element on a canvas, then create imagedata from canvas and pass it to jsPDF instance. I am not being able to put the svg element on the canvas.

Following is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import jsPDF from "jspdf";

const PdfDownload = () => {
  const circle = React.createRef();

  const generatePDF = () => {
    var svgCircle = document.getElementById("svg-container").innerHTML;
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvg(canvas, svgCircle);

    var imageData = svgCircle.toDataURL("image/png");
    var docPDF = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
    docPDF.addImage(imageData, "PNG", 40, 40, 75, 75);
    docPDF.save();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const svgElement = d3.select(circle.current);
    svgElement.append("circle").attr("cx", 150).attr("cy", 70).attr("r", 50);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="p-3">
        <span className="mb-3">
          <svg ref={circle} id="svg-container"></svg>
        </span>
        <Button onClick={generatePDF}>Generate Pdf</Button>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PdfDownload;
```

I am getting the error "canvg is not defined."

I have tried modifying the webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: function (config, env) {
    config.externals = {
      ...config.externals,
      canvg: "canvg",
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

But, I am still stuck on the same error. Is, there a straight forward method of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What is `canvg` ? It is not declared in your code

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks for reply. canvg is a method that puts svg element on the canvas. And, this is exactly what I am not able to figure out how to use it properly. Reactjs has a package canvg, but that doesn't resolves the issue. To use it I had to modify the webpack configurations using react-app-rewired package and it is the recommended method on jsPDF documentation as well. After all, that I am still not able to use canvg method in reacjs